# Where is "Set as Desktop Pitcures" button in share menu of Photo app?

Tags: macos, photos, wallpaper

From some time i can't set my photos as wallpaper. There isn't the option in sharing menu[image]

English:

- Shared Albums
- Mail
- Message
- AirDrop
- Notes
- Reminder
- Simulator
- Shortcuts 
  [] Edit Extensions...

macOS Ventura 13.4
MacBook Air M1

Comment: That's very unclear. This question should be improved with additional information such as : What have you already tried and in which ways didn't it work? Was macOS version are you running? etc.

Comment: Is this iOS or macOS?  What version?  I’m thinking macOS,  but I want to confirm

Comment: I have no Simulator entry. Can you deselect it under _Edit Extensions/Modifica estensioni_ and see what happens?

Comment: Funny because they explicitly mention "Set Wallpaper" in both [Use the Share menu on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-share-menu-on-mac-mh40614/13.0/mac/13.0) in the opener screenshot as well as in [Customize the desktop picture on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/choose-your-desktop-picture-mchlp3013/13.0/mac/13.0):
*To quickly use a photo you have in the Photos app, open Photos, select the photo, click the Share button in the Photos toolbar, then choose Set Wallpaper.*

Comment: On macOS Ventura there's also the problem of [missing keyboard navigation and worse accessibility in Safari](https://lapcatsoftware.com/articles/VenturaShare.html) of the redesigned 'floating' Share Menu.

Comment: cachius, if i deselect it, nothing append just "Simulator" Disappear